# Como organizar informações da DB printadas na pagina

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

Eu criei um painel, onde eu quero que mostre as informações que estão na db, estas são printadas na tela através do código:

```
<?php
$servidor = "localhost";
$usuario = "root";
$senha = "";
$dbname = "id8146007_contasadm";

$conn = mysqli_connect ($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $dbname);
$db_select = mysqli_select_db ($conn ,$dbname);

$query = sprintf ("SELECT email, ddd, numero, FROM contas");
$dados = mysqli_query ($conn,$query);
$linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($dados);
$total = mysqli_num_rows($dados);
?>
```

Até aí ok, porém as informações apenas ficam na tela, como eu faço para organiza-las? eu queria por um botão a frente de cada informação que aparecer, botão "excluir", o mesmo exclui a informação escolhida da DB. como eu o faria?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar uma tabela estilizada com CSS. O resultado seria este:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora para excluir o registro, recomendo excluir pelo id do usuário. Para isso, selecione também o id (se o nome da coluna for `id`) na consulta ao banco:

```
        ↓↓
"SELECT id, email, ddd, numero, FROM contas"
```

Códigos:

**CSS:**

```
table{
   width: 100%;
   background-color: #ddd;
   border-spacing: 1px;
}

th, td{
   padding: 10px;
   text-align: center;
}

table th{
   background-color: #444;
   color: #fff;
}

table td{
   background-color: #fff;
}

table tfoot td{
   background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

table tfoot td:first-child{
   text-align: right;
}
```

**HTML + PHP:**

```
<?php
$servidor = "localhost";
$usuario = "root";
$senha = "";
$dbname = "id8146007_contasadm";

$conn = mysqli_connect ($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $dbname);
$db_select = mysqli_select_db ($conn ,$dbname);

$id = $_GET['id'];
if($_GET['acao'] == 'excluir' && !empty(id)){
   // exclui o registro do banco
   mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM contas WHERE id = '$id'");
}

$query = sprintf ("SELECT id, email, ddd, numero, FROM contas");
$dados = mysqli_query ($conn,$query);
$linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($dados);
$total = mysqli_num_rows($dados);
?>
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>
         <strong>E-mail</strong>
      </th>
      <th>
         <strong>Número</strong>
      </th>
      <th>
      </th>
   </tr>
   <?php while($linha){ ?>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <?php echo $linha['email'] ?>
      </td>
      <td>
         (<?php echo $linha['ddd'] ?>) <?php echo $linha['numero'] ?>
      </td>
      <td>
         <button onclick='location.href = "?id=<?php echo $linha['id'] ?>&acao=excluir"'>Excluir</button>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <?php } ?>
   <tfoot>
      <td colspan="2">
         <strong>Total:</strong>
      </td>
      <td>
         <?php echo $total ?>
      </td>
   </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
if(isset($_GET['acao']) &&  $_GET['acao'] == 'excluir'){

$deletar = mysqli_query($conn,"delete from contas where email like '" . $_GET['email'] . "'");
}

$html = "<table><tr><td>Email</td><td>DDD</td><td>Conta</td><td></td></tr>";
while($res =  mysql_fetch_array( $dados )){

$html .= "<tr>
<td>" . $res['email'] . "</td>
<td>" . $res['ddd'] . "</td>
<td>" . $res['conta'] . "</td>
<td><a href=\"?acao=excluir&email=" . $res['email'] . "\">Excluir</a></td>
</tr>";

}

$html .= "</table>";

echo $html;
```